# Including common lisp string library in elisp

Tags: elisp, common-lisp, emacs24

How to include common-lisp string library in elisp?
Functions like `string-search, string-search-char` (@http://common-lisp.net/project/bknr/static/lmman/fd-str.xml) are not there in elisp library....

Comment: Google "elisp string library". Best of luck.

Comment: elisp is not common lisp. There are some similarities, and certain CL functions *are* implemented (which can assist with porting code in some cases), but in general don't expect to "include a common lisp library" in Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

Start with [Strings and Characters](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Strings-and-Characters.html).

Emacs Lisp handles strings differently than Common Lisp. Live with it!